# What is the python equivalent of MATLAB's pzplot?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

Is there a python equivalent of the pzplot function?

Here is the function for reference.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lti.pzplot.html

I did try searching for it, but only find result for matlab.
I am using the library called control which has a module for compatibility called control.matlab.

Comment: No equivalent. Custom [function example](https://www.dsprelated.com/showcode/244.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a direct equivalent.

There's a python control systems toolbox, which contains a `pzmap` [function](https://python-control.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/control.pzmap.html#control.pzmap).

Other than that, `pzplot` doesn't seem to be *that* useful. Just use `matplotlib.pyplot.plot` with different `markers` and make sure to disable the lines. `scatter` might also do the job. After all, pole-zero plots just makes circles and crosses on a plane.

In the end, what's special about `pzplot` is that it it takes a Matlab "System description" object, and extracts the pole and zero positions from that, before using the standard matlab plotting utilities to make the plot. There's no Python equivalent for that System description object, as far as I see, that you've already referring to in your question, so this all makes little sense. Plotting points is easy.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct equivalent, but you might want to look at `matplotlib` module, `polar` function:

```
# Implementation of matplotlib function
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms
import numpy as np
   
from matplotlib.transforms import offset_copy
   
xs = np.arange(-2, 2)
ys = np.cos(xs**2)
plt.polar(xs, ys) 
   
plt.title('matplotlib.pyplot.polar() function Example', fontweight ="bold")
plt.show()
```

output :

[image]

or use custom projection functionality of pyplot , here is a showcase of  [Hammer projection](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/custom_projection.html)